# I need an expert mysql opinion for doing a friends system

Tags: mysql

I need some help designing a friends system

The mysql table:
friends_ list
- auto_ id
- friend_ id
- user_ id
- approved_ status

Option 1 = Everytime a user adds a user there is 2 entries added to the DB, we then can get there friends like this

```
SELECT user_id FROM `friends_list` WHERE friend_id='$userId' and approved_status='yes'
```

---

Option 2 = We add 1 entry for every friend added and then get the friend list like this

```
SELECT friend_id AS FriendId FROM `friends_list` WHERE user_id='$userId' and approved_status='yes'
UNION
SELECT user_id as FriendId FROM `friends_list` WHERE friend_id='$userId' and approved_status='yes'
```

Of the 2 methods above for having friends on a site like myspace, facebook, all the other sites do, which of the 2 methods above would be best performance?

The 1st method doubles the ammount of rows, example a site with 2 million friend rows would only be 1 million rows the second method.

However does the union method mean there is 2 queries being made, so 2 queries on a million row table instead of 1?

---

**UPDATE**

I just ran some test on 60,000 friends and here are the results, and yes the tables are indexed.

Option 1 with 2 entries per friend;
.0007 seconds

Option 2 with 1 entry per friend using UNION to select
.3100 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1.

 Do as much work as possible on adding a friend. Adding someone is very rare compare to selecting all friends. Something probably done every time you render a page (on a social site).

Answer (score 0):

If you are indexing on user_id and friend_id, then the two statements should be equivalent in time -- best to test though -- DB's can have surprising results.  The UNION is seen by the database and it can use it to optimize the query, though.

Is friendship always mutual and with the same approval status?  If so, I'd opt for the second one.  If it can be one-way or with separate approvals, then you need the first one, right?

Comment: basicly user1 sends user2 a friend request, so the entry is marked as not approved, once user2 approves it is marked as approved, if user2 denies the request then the entry would be deleted.  If it is approved and either of them decide to not be friends anymore then they would delete the record.  I am not sure if the first method is required for this or not, I kinda get confused with it sometimes but it sounds to me like either method would work maybe

Comment: I should add that there is also a page to show all your pending friend request, meaning ones sent to you from other users where you can approve or deny/delete the record and then also another page showing the friend request that you sent to other users, it will show request you sent to user that did not approve or deny you yet AKA pending friend request page

Comment: i tested both ways, UNION seems to be much slower, I posted results in my post above

Comment: Do and time each select statement separately -- You can union it in code faster -- probably doesn't know that they are mutually exclusive and is trying to unique them.

Comment: I guess i'm not following what you are saying, how can I make the union faster?

Comment: What happens with the list of ids?  Do you put into a collection?  If so, do the left hand side, add to collection, then the right hand side and add to the collection.  The UNION isn't being optimized. You may be able to figure it out if one of the selects takes a lot longer than the other.  If they don't add up to the UNION time, then the UNION itself is slow -- my suggestion was that UNION doesn't know that the data is already unique and needs to do that work.

Answer (score 0):

Which dbms are you using? MySQL always use an extra temporary table when executing union queries. Creating these temporary tables creates some overhead to the query and is probably why your union query is slower than the first query.

Have you thought about separating friends and friend request? This would reduce the content of the friends table, you would also be able to delete accepted requests from the friend request table and keep the size of the table down. Another good advantage is that you keep less columns in each table and it is thereby easier to get a fine tuned index on them.

I am currently building this feature myself, and it would be interesting to hear about your experience on the matter.

Answer (score -1):

Answers to this kind of question tend to depend upong the usage patterns. In your case which is most common: adding new friendship relationships or querying the friendship realtionship?

Also you need to consider future flecibility, what otehr uses might there be for the data.

My guess is that option is a cleaner data model for what you are trying to represent. It looks like it allows for expandsion in directions such as asymmetric relationships, and friend of friends. I think that option will prove to be unweildy in the future.